# Error 504 in COUNTIFS while referencing other file

Tags: linux, csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Trying to calculate the following formula:

`=COUNTIFS('file:///home/user/PycharmProjects/my_project/My insights/Train/CSV/Train_tags.csv'#$Train_tags.L$1:L$1048576, "1")`

But it fails with error 504, despite being successfuly calculated with COUNTIF.
I need COUNTIFS (and not COUNTIF) because I want to stack more conditions.

Searched for `COUNTIFS` docs, searched for other issues but haven't seen anything related.
Any idea why it fails?

Comment: If you expect anyone to reproduce the issue (as first step for solving it), you should provide the relevant data - in your case: Train_tags.csv

Comment: I didn't think it was related to Train_tags.csv at all, since it works fine with COUNTIF. Thought it's a problem in the way I use COUNTIFS. Besides, Train_tags.csv is very huge. Let me think what I can add

Comment: Cross-posted to https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/150295/error-504-in-countifs-while-referencing-other-file/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggeling with this, I upgraded my LibreOffice version from 5 to 6 and it just worked. Probably a bug in version 5.

Comment: Bug [tdf#115162](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=115162) fixed for 5.4.6 and 6.0.1 References to external documents did not work in the *IFS() function family.